# Running script from .bash_profile does not run it at login. How can I fix?

Tags: bash, macos

I have a script to move files from my Downloads folder to Trash if they are more than x days old.

I want it to run every time I log in to my mac.

However, it only runs once I open Terminal. How do I fix this?

I put this in my .bash_profile

```
#Delete all files in Downloads more than X days old
/usr/local/bin/delete_downloads.sh
```

Comment: Logging in to your mac doesn't mean necessarily you're running `bash`. Try another script, e.g. startup files.

Comment: If you're login shell is bash, try `~/.bash_login` create it if does not exists.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want it to run when you log into the Mac and not when you start Terminal.  You can add the script to: System Preferences -> Users & Groups -> Login Items